# How to send POST requests with array properties (Ionic 2 HTTP plugin)?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

In one of my Ionic 2 projects I need to send a POST request to a server with a JSON body that looks like this:

```
var body = { "prop" : 1, 
  "prop2" : "Test", 
  "prop3": [{ "id" : "1", "qty": 1, "details": "Test" }] 
}
```

I am using the following code to call the server using the native HTTP plugin (1.2.0) in Android:

```
http.post(url, body, {}).then(function() { ... })
```

But my server is receiving the following:

```
{ "prop" : 1, 
  "prop2" : "Test", 
  "prop3": "[{ \"id\" : \"1\", \"qty\": 1, \"details\": \"Test\" }]"
}
```

As you can see, the array property "prop3" is being turned into a string, so my server is failing to parse it because it's expecting an array, not a string.

One of the things I could do is to change the server side code to parse this string back into an array (but that would be far from ideal). The other thing I could do is to parse the JSON object manually with JSON.stringify.

So, is this just a bug in the plugin or am I missing something here?

[**Native HTTP plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/http/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after taking a look at the plugin's source code (the Java one, I'm testing my application in Android) it seems that I won't be able to use the plugin as is (I would need to modify it). What I found was this:

In CordovaHttpPost.java, the body of the request is sent as Form data (simple key-values).

```
request.form(this.getParams());  //Map<?, ?>
```

That's why my array property is converted into a string (and any other complex object for that matter)

TL;DR this plugin is only useful to send simple JSON key-value objects (no nesting, no complex objects, no arrays, etc.).

Comment: what happen when you use `JSON.stringify(body)`? did you test that?

Comment: It gives a "JSON Error", the post method expects an Object for the "body" parameter.

Comment: What is the solution for it? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @BalrajAllam I ended up not modifying the plugin. What I did was just to parse the JSON values (strings) server-side. I know it's an ugly solution, but it was the quickest way.

Answer (score 4):

Try set `http.setDataSerializer("json");`
And send data as usual: `http.post(url, body, {})`

Then http plugin will send data with application/json content type and support deep structure of json, as stated in the documentation:
https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http#setdataserializer