# Post JSON array with IONIC 2/3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to send a JSON array as parameter using HTTP native with IONIC 3. This is the request:

```
 HTTPResponse = await this.http.post(url, 
 body, headers);
```

This is the complete code. I'm using HTTP from from '@ionic-native/http'. This is the complete code

```
 import { HTTP, HTTPResponse } from '@ionic-native/http';

 [...]

 let body =  '[{"userId": 1, "timestamp":"2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02", 
 "audit":"MENUTEST"},{"userId": 1, "timestamp":"2018-10-
 12T18:00:00.000+02", "audit":"MENUTEST"},{"userId": 1, 
 "timestamp":"2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02", "audit":"MENUTEST"}]';

 //Auth header
 let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`};

 let httpResponse: HTTPResponse = await 
 this.http.post(URL_data, JSON.parse(body), headers);
```

I'm using similar code with other request and all is going fine, the only difference is that the request that is going have a simple parameters in JSON body. This is the request that is going fine:

```
import { HTTP, HTTPResponse } from '@ionic-native/http';

[...]

let body = '{ "username": "usuario.prueba1", "password": "' + 
Md5.hashStr('prueba') + '", "customerCode": "1234DEV" }';

let httpResponse: HTTPResponse = await 
this.http.post(URL_login, JSON.parse(body), headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

If you have a look at the [source-file](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http/blob/0407a561fcb8c3e4a6b369aaacee93494ae7dcac/src/android/com/synconset/cordovahttp/CordovaHttpPlugin.java#L39) of the android implementation of the post action you will see that a JsonObject is expected as parameter, this is why passing an array will result in a `JSON error`. You have to wrap the array in an object like that to make this work:

```
let body = {
  myArray: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      timestamp: '2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02',
      audit: 'MENUTEST',
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      timestamp: '2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02',
      audit: 'MENUTEST',
    },
    {
      userId: 1,
      timestamp: '2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02',
      audit: 'MENUTEST',
    },
  ],
};

let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
let httpResponse: HTTPResponse = await this.http.post(
  URL_data,
  body,
  headers,
);
```

**Old answer:**

I guess your `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you need to add a name for you parameter which is separated from the value by an equal sign (`=`):

```
let payload = [{ "userId": 3, "timestamp": "2018-10-12T18:00:00.000+02", "audit": "Mensaje 3" }, { "userId": 4, "timestamp": "2018-10-13T18:00:00.000+02", "audit": "Mensaje 4" }];
let body = `MyArray=${payload}`;
```

The relevant part of the specification can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). Point 2. says:

> The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&'.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to give you more information. The issue is related to IONIC 3 and i need a valid code for this framework.

Comment: Ah you should have mentioned that you are using the native HTTP plugin, please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I have tested your code but it's not valid for server side. I have tried to send JSON by REST client and all is going fine. but i cannot create the same body in my client app. Your code include myarray field that it is not expected by server. Any addional idea?

Comment: Then you have to change either your server side code so it _can_ read json object or you do not use the ionic-native http plugin. You could also use angulars HttpModule to make this call.

Comment: FInally i have used angulars module, but the main problem i had was -c -l paramaters in app execution. These parameters are modifying behaviour in request. Content-type was being ignored. Thanks a lot, but the problem probably was not in the code.

Comment: Jep livereload is almost always causing some wired behaviour. I'm glad you could finally solve it though.

Comment: same here, when i post object with array, array posted but with null values.. what i have to do??

Answer (score -1):

To support deep structure, you should change serializer.
Try set `http.setDataSerializer("json");` And send data as usual: `http.post(url, body, {})`

Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589124/6097876